# Allow question marks (?) in WordPress permalinks

Tags: urls, url-rewriting, query-string, permalinks

I have migrated an older site to WordPress and need to keep all legacy URLs.  I am using a plugin called Custom Permalinks for that purpose, which works well, except for one thing: it strips all "?" and "=" characters from URLs, a so-called "sanitation" function.

This is a problem, because some post URLs are in the following format:

```
/storyview.php?storyid=20100215-72849
```

I have found the sanitation code in the plugin's PHP files and inserted additional special character exceptions, by modifying the code from:

```
    $permalink = preg_replace( '/[^%a-z0-9 \.\/_-]/', '', $permalink );
```

to

```
    $permalink = preg_replace( '/[^%a-z0-9 \.\/_?\-=]/', '', $permalink );
```

As a result, the "?" and "=" characters are no longer stripped from permalink URLs.  However, URLs with "?" in them return a 404.  URLs with just a "=" and no "?" resolve correctly to the assigned WordPress post.

Some sources are suggesting that the question mark may be interfering with WordPress's query parameters.  I want to know:

1. whether that's really the issue and
2. how I can work around it in order to get the permalink structure above.  I am not concerned about trading some query parameter functionality for getting all legacy URLs to work.

Comment: The ? in a URL means that anything following it is considered a variable/parameter - so yes, the ? is interfering with the Wordpress query parameters.    It is unclear what exactly you are trying to do - Wordpress should automatically handle these parameters without any plugin.  If you need to do redirection from URLs which include parameters to "pretty" URL's then you should be looking at redirection rather then "Custom Permalinks" if that is what you are trying to achieve.   The redirection would need to be based on the query parameters.

Comment: Hi, which part of my question is unclear?  I need to preserve post URLs that existed in the old CMS prior to migrating to WordPress.  Therefore, it's custom permalinks that are needed here, not redirection.  I've included above the exact format in which these URLs need to be, and many of these old URLs do have question marks in them.  They are not parameters in this case.  They are copy-and-pasted URLs from the old CMS.

Comment: If you need to preserve permalinks why do you need that plugin? Wordpress should do this by default. The URLs without questionmarks can be processed with Wordpress's pretty permalinks.

Comment: I think we are talking about completely different things.  Are you claiming that WordPress allows you to set individual custom permalinks for every post out of the box?  How in the world does pretty permalinks allow to achieve a URL like /storyview.php?storyid=20100215-72849 ?

Comment: Sort of.  In Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks you can have "plain" or set a custom structure - the postname can be keyed off the "slug" for the post/page. This does not let you create an arbitrary structure though.  I've not tried it but I wonder if you could use a Custom Structure of **/storyview.php?storyid=%postname%** and set the slug to 20100215-72849.   Absent knowing what storyview.php actually does though, I might create new pages in Wordpress as standard pages/posts, and then use redirection on the parameters to the new pages....

Comment: An alternative - again dependent on what exactly what storyview.php does and your webserver might be to use htaccess rules to rewrite the URL (which again is a type of redirect)...   The point being however that despite your assertions to the contrary the webserver is calling the page storyview.php, and the storyid and number after it are indeed parameters processed by storyid.

Comment: It may be worth you clarifying if 20100215-72849 is a reference to post 72849  (written on 15 Feb 2010), and if so if post 72849 exists in the new Wordpress instance.   Also, is the web server running Apache and if so can you modify .htaccess. Lastly do you really want to preserve the old ugly link format  or is it appropriate to translate [redirect]  it into a pretty link?

Comment: @Dave Your desired permalinks are not valid. The question marks _are_ parameters in your old links. You old CMS is just built to use those parameters. WordPress is not. Your are not going to be able to use this format for your permalinks. You will need redirects to redirect from this old format for one supported by WordPress.

Comment: @davidgo Yes, preserving the ugly URLs is the point of the exercise. Lots of outside linkage to them and preserving the links is better than redirecting (from an SEO standpoint anyway). Storyview.php doesn't exist anymore: it's a remnant of the old CMS. The idea was to trick WordPress into generating these real-looking (but fake) URLs. Everything works, except for the "?." I did try your proposed structure of /storyview.php?storyid=%postname% but it returns a 404. As suspected (and concurred by Jacob above), the "?" confuses WordPress because it's interfering with WP's own URL-writing method.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Interestingly, ChatGPT suggested a workaround of substituting ? with a placeholder, such as @@Q@@, and then using custom code in functions.php to rewrite it back to a question mark on the fly.  Presumably, that gets around WordPress's query parameters.  Obviously, copying and pasting ChatGPT's code is a crapshoot, and it didn't work for me anyway. I'm not that well-versed in PHP to write a unique solution.

Comment: Is the 404 being genetated by Wordpress or the OS? (ie is .htaccess being parsed to feed to feed storyview.php through Wordpress?) If not an imperfect hack might be to copy index.php to storyview.php -

Comment: @davidgo That's a cool idea, but this format (/storyview.php?storyid=20100215-72849) is only needed for some posts (I mentioned this in the OP).  Other posts have different permalink formats (no question mark, no equal sign).  So the only solution is assigning permalinks per post instead of systematically rewriting these URLs.

Comment: What resoyrces do you have at your dispodal?  Maybe the solution is to put the whole Wordpress install behind a proxy and let the proxy translate the requests.  Maybe even something like Cloudflare.   Also- I know you are resistant to the idea but it might be wise to talk to an SEO person to satisfy yourself about the true SEO cost of using redirects, as you are accruing/creating technical debt and I expect you will land up paying for it. It may be better to handle now.

Comment: I am the SEO person :)  Reviving zombie permalinks versus implementing 301s to fresh and clean URLs should be decided on a case-by-case basis.  In this case, it's warranted, but I'm not planning to expend much beyond the energy that's already been put in.  I'll watch this thread for a few days and will probably go with 301 redirects if nothing else comes up.

Comment: "and inserted additional special character exceptions" - The code you posted does not create an "exception", in fact it looks like it does the complete opposite... those characters are "stripped" from the variable `$permalink`. It's more likely that the query string is not present in the `$permalink` to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using a plugin called Custom Permalinks for that purpose, which works well, except for one thing: it strips all "?" and "=" characters from URLs, a so-called "sanitation" function.

This needs taking up with the plugin authors for the `=`, and is likely because WP itself would perform the same sanitisation, but `?` won't work for the reasons listed below regardless of the plugin used.

> Some sources are suggesting that the question mark may be interfering with WordPress's query parameters. I want to know:
>
> whether that's really the issue and

Yes. WP should be okay with `=`, but it will only process the URL parts that come *before* the first `?` character in the pretty permalink system.

So this URL: `/example=test?storyid=123` will always be processed as the pretty URL `example=test` by WordPress

## Why `?` can't be used in pretty permalinks/slugs

The fundamental problem is that WP does not consider the `?` to be a part of the permalink, and only considers everything *before* the `?`.

If we look at `parse_request` in the WP class which is responsible for taking rewrite rules and matching the URL against them, we see this:

```php
            list( $req_uri ) = explode( '?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
```

`$req_uri` is what is used to match rewrite rules further down ( there's some logic that assigns it to a new variable unless the request is empty in which case it doesn't use rewrite rules ).

This means that no matter how many `?` characters there are in the request URI the rewrite rule itself, the post slug, or their location in the string, they will never be considered for the permalink handling process, WP considers them GET parameters/URL query parameters and treats them accordingly. Only the "path" as PHP considers it is evaluated, which for `test.php?foo=bar` results in `/test.php`.

This is why you can't match posts with `?` in their slug using rewrite rules, because everything after and including the first `?` is ignored when evaluating the rules.

### What About Ugly Permalinks?

Despite this, nothing prevents the ugly `index.php?name=....` from being used to access a post with a slug that contains a `?`, though it may then do a canonical redirect that breaks it, but those can be disabled.

#### Could This Be Overriden?

If you wanted to change this, you'd need to replace the entire rewrite rule engine, as well as some follow up code. Specifically the `parse_request` filter would need to be used to throw away the previous result and undo what it did, then put your own in. You would also need to filter the sanitisation code to allow `?`. note that this means the rewrite rule process would run twice, and you would need to keep your copy up to date to include bug fixes made upstream. This is also ignoring the problems this might cause elsewhere with permalinks that no longer match when `?` is used, so you'll need to include very specific exceptions for the cases that you need it to work in.

Take a look at `wp-includes/class-wp.php`, in particular `parse_request` and the `main` function for more context.

## What About `=`?

I can't find any evidence against this, renaming `test.php` to `foo=bar.php` reveals `$req_uri` to be `/foo=bar.php`.

---

## how I can work around it?

> how I can work around it in order to get the permalink structure above. I am not concerned about trading some query parameter functionality for getting all legacy URLs to work.

Fundamentally, you don't need the URL parameters to be in the post slug for it to be in the permalink. In fact the slug could be ignored completely.

Take as an example post permalinks that use the post ID e.g. `/p/123`. Nothing stops you from registering a query variable named `storyid` that then gets automatically picked up from the GET variables, then writing a filter to take `get_query_var( 'storyid' )` and modify the main query to put its value in the post ID parameter, or add a post meta query to match it. the rest would be a matter of filtering the URLs to look the way you want them. Only `storyview.php` would need to match in the rewrite rule system.

Note that there are many many ways of doing this, but none of them involve putting URL parameters in pretty permalinks in the way your question asked.

Comment: Is there an easier way to do this, such as renaming the WordPress file that serves content to viewstory.php, so that the "viewstory.php?" part can be generated by WordPress (I understand the rename would probably need to be performed after every WordPress version update) and taking care of the rest of the URL via a permalink plugin?

Comment: nothing prevents you having a permalink that starts with `viewstory.php` when registering a CPT, and you can put the rest of the URL in there it just won't be considered by the rewrite engine, but you don't have to. It's a shame you can't use 301 redirects as you could create a page with that slug and redirect on `$_GET['storyid']`

Comment: I bring up renaming the php file in order to get the question mark part generated by WordPress as part of it's out-of-the-box settings --the 'Plain' option under Permalink settings, which is https://example.com/?p=123, and then manipulate the URL via permalink plugins from that point.  The plugins can do everything except the question mark.  If 301s were an acceptable solution in this case, then I would just abandon this archaic structure and go with pretty URLs.

Comment: my understanding was that you'd already figured out how to do that via a plugin, but couldn't get the posts to load on the frontend, is that not the case? Note that setting the permalinks up when the CPT is registered would be easier in some ways, and something you could ask about on the stack, unlike the plugin route

Comment: The current situation is that with modifying most custom permalink plugins' code, Wordpress will write any URL, including putting as many ? as you want in forbidden places, as well as =.  But yes, it will not serve actual content if you do that (it serves content fine with = in the URL).  So I am currently stalled.  My question was whether renaming an actual php file to viewstory.php would make it easier in combination with enabling the example.com/?p=123  format so that I could get the first part of the URL right.

Comment: I mentioned the `get_query_var` trick a few times in the answer and in the comments on it, you don't need WP to accept the entire URL with the URL parameters in the rewrite rules, just the part before the `?`, everything after that can be handled by a filter that looks for `storyid` and then changes the query parameters to find the right post. If it's a code snippet you want though then you need to ask for it, e.g. in a `pre_get_posts` `$q->set( 'name' => 'storyview.php?storyid=' . get_query_var( 'storyid' ) );`. To achieve this you need to know how to add a query var and use `pre_get_posts`

Comment: renaming an actual PHP file wouldn't make the rewrites easier, that moves you away from rewrite rules completely and leads to bootstrapping WP from scratch and a lot of brand new problems and fragile code, but as you said that's a new question, not this question, if you have a new Q create a new Q. Also I'd suggest editing the question and briefly explaining why 301 redirects aren't an option for you, there are no SEO reasons to do this, and it would not break old links. Note this isn't a discussion board, if we try to discuss it here it will eventually auto-flag the entire thing

Comment: Unless you work at Google Search, you can't state with confidence how exactly 301s affect or do not affect SEO.  As of today, although not significantly, redirects do affect PR, and they affect it quite a bit when they lead to another domain. There is no reason to lose even 5% of the link juice if you can retain all of it.  But there are other important reasons, like the psychological effect on the visitor when he clicks on one link but is taken to another.  Also, if you've been cited in a thousand books as Larry, you don't want to become known as Sergey, even with perfect 301 redirects.

Comment: Ultimately, whether 301s are acceptable or not is irrelevant. You may not find the user's reasons for doing things valid, but the issue as written is valid.  Also, this site might as well become a discussion board, maybe it would breathe some life into it. Not the wisest decision by Stack Exchange management to spin WP out of Webmasters. Questions had more exposure and very quick answers on Webmasters SE. *Edit*: sorry, I missed your comment about `get_query_var` etc. I dont know what those things mean. I dont know PHP or understand queries, just running a WP site. My question got moved here.

Comment: Not my call to make, the process for creating new stacks is community driven, but if you do want to talk about the stack itself there's a meta stack for that, discussions, especially meta discussions are heavily discouraged on the stack itself. I'd strongly recommend looking up `get_query_var`, what query variables are, and how to add new ones.